# unable to resolve module path in login in src

Tags: module, path, src

[

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'

 

import Login from './android/app/src/Login'
import flexbox from './android/app/src/flexbox'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

function MyStack() {
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
      name = 'Login'
      component= {Login}/>
      
      <Stack.Screen
      name = 'flexbox'
      component={flexbox}/>
      

      
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App(){
  return(
    <Navigation Container>
      <My Stack/>
    </Navigation Container>

  )
}
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYK2z.jpg)

originmodulepath "c:\users\hp\Downloads\task\App.js","targetModuleName"::./src/Login","message"."Unable to resolve module

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing full path I think you should write the path related to the current location of your file. I mean, if your file is located in /android/app/src and you need import Login that is located in the same directory then a correct import could be

> import Login from './Login'